# "null or not an object" error in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-8

My web site works on all browsers except IE8. The following code error on the fourth line of code with `position().left` is null or not an object. Has anyone seen an fixed this type of IE8 jQuery bug?

```
$(".navref").click(function(){
    var m = Math.floor(($(window).width()-997)/2);
    m = m < 0 ? 0 : m;  //if screen is smaller than 997, force align to left
    var l = $("#"+$(this).attr('rel')).position().left;
    var lt = 200;
    if($(this).attr('rel') == 'page1') lt = 400;
    l = l+(lt-m);
    l = l < 0 ? 0 : l;

    //,onAfter:function(){checkScreens()}
    $('html, body').stop(true,false).scrollTo(l,2000,{easing:'easeInOutCubic'});

    return false;
 });
```

The web site is http://sputtens.com.

Comment: `$(this).attr('rel')` => `this.rel`

Comment: `Math.floor(($(window).width()-997)/2);` -> `(($(window).width()-997)/2) |0;`

Comment: Did you check the code in other browsers? in which it works?

Answer (score 5):

This tells you that `$("#"+$(this).attr('rel'))` is not matching any elements, and so `position()` returns `null`. If you find out why that is, it should sort it out.

Just change the code to this:

```
var id = $(this).attr('rel');
var element = $("#"+id);
var l = element.position().left;
```

...and walk through that with the F12 debugging tools, looking at the `id` and comparing it with what you have in the DOM, looking at the result of the query for the element with that ID, etc.

Comment: If so, this has nothing to do with IE8. People must stop say it doesn't work at Browser X if they check only in that browser. :(

Comment: @gdoron: Indeed they do, I see it all too often. :-) Not that I'm saying the OP did in this case, it's easy enough to change more than one thing when checking things cross-browser and trick yourself up. Or of course, IE could be continuing to play silly buggers with `attr` despite Resig and crew's best efforts. (+1 on your comment on the question, btw.)